# a linux script to get workstation ip then save it and upload it to cloud

Tags: bash, cloud, storage

Is it possible to write a linux script which can find the ip address of the workstation and then save ip to a local file then upload the file to cloud? i.e.,

1. get ip from bash;
2. save it to a local file;
3. sync this file to google drive etc.

Thanks.

Edit: this script is monitoring the ip if ip changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 and 2: try `hostname -i > /path/to/filename` or `hostname -I  > /path/to/filename`

Comment: thanks. I think the 3 could be got around by saving the file to a dropbox folder. But I still want to improve 1. and 2. How to write a script to use the bash command you are giving? basically the script will run 'hostname -i > /path/to/dropboxfolder/file' like every 10min for example.

Comment: You need a [cron job](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) to run a script every x minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the classical dynamic dns services like described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS

I would use the following script to send an email:

```
#!/bin/bash
function hostnameChange() {
    hostname -i > hostname_new
    if diff -q hostname_old hostname_new 2>/dev/null; then # no change
        return
    fi
    mv hostname_new hostname_old
    { # sendmail brace
        echo "To:   youmail@googlemail.com";
        echo "Subject: ip";
        echo
        hostname -i
    } | /usr/lib/sendmail
}
hostnameChange
```

Or upload the file (hostname_old) to pastebin instead of using the sendmail braces:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108493/easy-way-to-paste-command-line-output-to-paste-bin-services

To run this via cron, use `crontab -e`, this will bring up an editor ($EDITOR).

```
*/10 * * * * /path_to_your_script
```

Comment: thanks. Is this snippet a bash script? and also can you tell me how to improve the code by adding something such that 'hostname' will update the ip every 10min or so?

Comment: yes, it is a bash function: put it into a file, call the function name `hostnameChange` and make it executable using `chmod a+x file`. The first line should be a [shebang](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang) line `#!/bin/bash` and start it via cronjob, as Cyrus said.